# creating a mandatory field in an Outlook appointment

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Sub AddMandatoryFieldToCurrentAppointment()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim olPage As Object
    Dim olControls As Object
    

    Set olPage = olItem.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Appointment")
    Set olControls = olPage.Controls
    
 
    With olControls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        .Left = 100
        .Top = 100
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 20
        .Name = "MandatoryField"
        .Caption = "Mandatory Field:"
        .ValidationText = "This field is mandatory."
        .Required = True
    End With
    
 
    Set olControls = Nothing
    Set olPage = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

while running my VBA Script, I encounter Runtime error 91, which says my With Blockvariable is not set.

The creation of a Textfield in my Outlook session ( Appointment )